# flir on caption of Lightbox

Tags: jquery, lightbox

I'm wondering how you could add flir on the captions of a lightbox. I already managed to display the flir on the first picture you select but when you go to the next picture without closing lightbox the caption is regular text.

this is how my footer looks

```
<script src="/js/flir.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
FLIR.init();
....
</script>
```

and

in the lightbox js file in the _resize_container_image_box function

```
$('#lightbox-container-image-box').animate({ width: intWidth, height: intHeight },settings.containerResizeSpeed,function() { _show_image();FLIR.auto([ 'span' ]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the answer:

$('#lightbox-image-details-caption').removeClass('flir-replaced');
$('#lightbox-image-details-caption').removeAttr('flirReplaced');
then FLIR.replace(['span'])